read a hex string over UART for PIC Microcontrollers in C using mikroC for PIC
I'm using a PIC18F microcontroller with mikroC PRO for PIC.
The PIC micro reads strings over the UART, which Software implemented because there is only one UART, and I need two.
I'm trying to write a copy of **"void UARTx_Read_Text(char Output, char Delimiter, char Attempts);" function and my code seem reluctant and suboptimal.
Can anyone please help me improve my code?
Thanks to all the answers,
Yishai,
The code block:
/*
 * Prototype   : void Soft_UART_Read_Text(char *S, char *Delimiter, char Attempts);
 * Returns     : Nothing
 * Description : Reads characters received via UART until the delimiter sequence is detected.
 *               The read sequence is stored in the parameter output; delimiter sequence is stored in the parameter delimiter.
 *               This is a blocking call: the delimiter sequence is expected, otherwise the procedure exits (if the delimiter is not found).
 * Parameters  : S         - Received text
 *               Delimiter - Sequence of characters that identifies the end of a received string.
 *               Attempts  - Defines number of received characters in which Delimiter sequence is expected.
 *                           If Attempts is set to 255, this routine will continuously try to detect the Delimiter sequence.
 * Requires    : Nothing
 * Example     : UART1_Read_Text(output, "OK", 10);    // reads text until 'OK' is found
 */
 void 
 Soft_UART_Read_Text(char *S, char *Delimiter, char Attempts)
 {
     int DelimiterLength = strlen(Delimiter);
     int StringLength = BUFF_SIZE; // string length
     char i = 0;
     char DelimiterCount = 0;
     char read_byte;
     
     while(DelimiterCount <= DelimiterLength)
     {
         read_byte = Soft_UART_Read(&error);
         if(error) PORTD.B1 = 1;
         else PORTD.B1 = 0;
             
         if(read_byte == Delimiter[DelimiterCount])
         {
             DelimiterCount++;
             if(DelimiterCount == DelimiterLength)
                 break;
         }
         else
         {
             *(S+i) = read_byte;
             //i++;
             if(++i > StringLength) i= 0;
             if(Attempts < 255)
             {
                 if(Attempts == i)
                    break;
             }
         }
     }
 }

Write C code to read string over the UART,
Improve my C code.

If this is working code, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable. If it isn't working code, then what's wrong with it?

You need to reset DelimiterCount at some point, otherwise "OK" is "found" in the string "datadatadataOdatadataKdatadata"

I removed the C++ tag, this is clearly "C" (and C++ is a different language)

Some low hanging fruit: DelimiterCount <= DelimiterLength instead of < is almost always a bug. *(S+i) instead of S[i] is always bad style. if(++i > StringLength) looks like a bug as it will break 1 item early. A whole lot of these potential bugs could be avoided by using plain, readable for loops instead.

Thank you for your reply. You have a suggestion for better implementation. Can you please share a working and better-implemented one?
